# problema etiquetas apertura php

Tags: php

Hola gente estoy trabajando con php (versión 5.6.22-4) en la plataforma osgeolive (versión 10.5)y estoy teniendo problemas con las etiquetas de apertura de php.
si pongo

```
    <?php
```

me sale esto en la web
[image: usando etiqueta <?php]
si pongo

```
    <?
```

me sale esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto el codigo PHP del archivo listarClientes.php

```
    <?
      // capa control 
      require_once('modelo.php'); 
      require_once('accesoadatos.php'); 
      $objClienteAD = new clienteAD;
      $listaCliente = $objClienteAD->listar();
    ?>
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 70px">Id</td>
                <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 222px">Nombre</td>
                <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 88px">Estado</td>
            </tr>
    <?
       foreach($listaCliente as $cliente)
            { 
    ?>

            <tr>
                <td style="width: 70px"><?php echo $cliente['ruc'];?></td>
                <td style="width: 222px"><?php echo $cliente['nombre']; 
    ?>          </td>
                <td style="width: 88px"><?php echo $cliente['estado'];
    ?>         </td>
          </tr>             
    <?
            }
    ?>
    </table>
```

alguien sabe donde está el problema??
pd: este código de ejemplo funcionaba anteriormente pero luego comenzó a suceder esto

Comment: Lo más seguro es que no tienes activado o instalado un servidor apache para interpretar php

Comment: @Lixus sisi amigo xq este código antes andaba en la misma maquina virtua ademas me está levantando el localhost y tiene los archivos php.ini

Comment: El archivo está dentro de la carpeta www del servidor o similar como en wamp donde se ejecute el código php en la página?

Comment: el php.ini está en otra carpeta y el listarClientes.php está dentro de la www

Comment: Tampoco ha servido de reiniciar el servidor y/o el php... no?

Comment: te comento activé esa opcion que dijiste y no hubo mas problemas con las etiquetas ahora estoy revisando la cadena de conexion a postgresql , tal vez no esté andando aunque antes si andaba.. es raro eso

Comment: Es decir que si hubo un problema con los `short_open_tag ` y ahora tienes otro problema? (Si quieres dirigirte a alguien en los comentarios tienes que poner un `@` por delante del nombre del usuario, ej. `@aldanux` )

Comment: Debería poner correctamente las etiquetas de apertura y cierre:
<?php echo "Buenas prácticas";
?>

Comment: @aldanux claro aparentemente el ya no hay problemas con las etiquetas pero el codigo no está funcionando cuando antes si lo hacia

Comment: Ok... puedes ser mas detallado? Que no está funcionando ahora?

Comment: @aldanux cuando instancio a la clase conexion para ver si se puede conectar a la BD no muestra nada ( ni error ni OK) , voy a tener que crear otro tema para este problema verdad?? asi adjunto el archivo conexion

Comment: Me temo que si... recuperaré la respuesta dada ya que soluciono una parte... para la otra parte crea un nuevo post con el máximo detalle posible... y a ver si entre todos podemos ayudarte... suerte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que poner en tu [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php)

`short_open_tag = On`

> Indica a PHP si debería permitirse la forma abreviada de las etiquetas
>   de apertura de PHP

`<? ?>`

> Si se quiere utilizar PHP junto con XML,
>   se puede desactivar esta opción para poder usar  en línea. Si
>   no, puede imprimirse con PHP, por ejemplo:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; ?>
```

> Además, si está desactivada, se debe usar
>   siempre la forma no abreviada de la etiqueta de apertura de PHP

```
<?php ?>
```

Comment: pero el tema es que no me acepta ninguna de las etiquetas, voy a revisar eso que dices pero no creo que me funcione

Comment: @fer - vale mira lo... no me di cuenta que falla también con `<?php` ... intenta de reiniciar tu servidor/php

Comment: estoy reiniciando el servidor ahora, active el short_tag pero no creo que sea eso